# Открыть новую вкладку при нажатии кнопки

Tags: html

Доброго времени суток, господа знатоки :) Подскажите пожалуйста как можно при нажатии кнопки открыть новую вкладку. Я нашел только такой вариант, но он перенаправляет текущую, не то что хотелось бы. Без JS.

```html
<button onClick='location.href="http://google.com/"'>VIEW MORE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">VIEW MORE</a>
```

Используй target="_blank"

Comment: Я так понимаю к кнопке это не применимо? Подскажите тогда для чего же тогда годятся button помимо отправки формы?

Comment: форму отправить годятся))